# Distinct IList and select second element

Tags: c#, list, linq, distinct, linq-group

I have an IList collection

```
public IList<MyObject> Items
```

I can group that list and take first element of each group

```
Items.GroupBy(x => x.Type).Select(grp => grp.First()).ToList();
```

How can I group that list and take not first element (for example: second) ??

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Enumerable.ElementAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb299233%28v=vs.100%29.aspx):

```
var everySecond = Items.GroupBy(x => x.Type).Select(grp => grp.ElementAt(1)).ToList();
```

If there are not so many items you can use [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386(v=vs.100).aspx) which returns null instead(for reference types).

**Edit**: "*i have selectedItem and want to display that in group as main element*":

So actually you want to get the first that matches a specific condition, in this case it is the selected, you can  order the group and  take the first:

```
var everySelected = Items
    .GroupBy(x => x.Type)
    .Select(grp => grp.OrderByDescending(x => x == selectedItem).First())
    .ToList();
```

I have used `OrderByDescending`(consider that true is 1 and false is 0) with the comparison. In this way every item that is the same reference as your selected item comes first(replace it with the logic how you want to compare them instead of reference equality).

Comment: But i don't know the index of that element. Can i select by element ?

Comment: @ArmenMkrtchyan: but you have mentioned that you want  to take _"for example: second"_. What means "select by element"?

Comment: i have selectedItem and want to display that in group as main element